# ember.js header of page as controller/view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a bit of problem with new router. I would like to have header which is a separate controller-view. And to be honest I'm not sure how to achieve it.

I tried to define footer and header in index controller/template and  in IndexRoute do redirect to "gallerys" route but then the index template is ommited.

With previous router I created index template with: 
    {{outlet "hedaer"}}
    {{outlet "body" }}
    {{outlet "footer"}}

But now, I'm not sure how to connect it all.

Comment: I think I found a solution: use ApplicationView and ApplicationController to handle all header&footer "stuff". But I'm still not sure if it's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the application template like this:

```
{{render header}}
{{outlet}}
{{render footer}}
```

The render helper will lookup both HeaderView class, and the instance of the headerController and connect them. The same with footer.